# Dialogflow WebhookRequest parameter list empty in C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, dialogflow-es

I use @sys.geo-city for a parameter, but the request doesn't pick it up:

```
{ 
"responseId": "bd9ad2dd-9a8b-4c66-a1c1-4731dc5a66d2-d5ae01f3", 
"queryResult": 
{ 
    "queryText": "weather", 
    "parameters": { }, 
    "allRequiredParamsPresent": true,
    "fulfillmentText": "Let's check the weather.", 
    "intent": 
    { 
         "name": "projects/dtc-agent-1-uhoquf/agent/intents/8dde7daa-fd8e-4bd1-8b12-44cb72290d6c",
         "displayName": "Weather" 
    }, 
    "intentDetectionConfidence": 1, "languageCode": "en" 
},
"originalDetectIntentRequest": { "payload": { } }, 
"session": "projects/dtc-agent-1-uhoquf/agent/sessions/cf762b76-13aa-1fd8- fb92-6ee480ec2c5e" }
```

Seems like "parameters" should contain the parameters I put in the Dialogflow console for the Weather intent.

In my C# .NET Web API controller I have:

```
[HttpPost]
public WebhookResponse Post([FromBody] WebhookRequest webhookRequest)
{
   WebhookResponse webhookResponse = new WebhookResponse();     
   webhookResponse.FulfillmentText = webhookRequest.ToString(); 
   return webhookResponse;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are right, it should.

One thing that is definitely wrong with your code is the way you parse the `WebhookRequest`. Injecting it with the `[FromBody]` tag will use the system default JSON parser, which is incorrect. You need to explicitly use the Protobuf parser from the `Google.Protobuf` namespace (should be included with the `Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.V2` package):

```csharp
[HttpPost]
public WebhookResponse Post([FromBody] string requestString)
{
  var requestParser = new Google.Protobuf.JsonParser(
    Google.Protobuf.JsonParser.Settings.Default.WithIgnoreUnknownFields(true));
  WebhookRequest webhookRequest = requestParser.Parse<WebhookRequest>(requestString);
  // ...
}
```

Note that the setting to ignore unknown fields may not always be necessary, but is convenient to avoid throwing an exception when the request format gets extended in the future.